# FCM Malformed Topic Name

Tags: node.js, firebase-cloud-messaging, firebase-admin

I have created a push notification with the rest api and everything works as expected.

I have decided to change from the rest api and use `admin.messaging().send(message)`.

My topic names are all numbers so the 1st error I got was:

> anyMessage.topic.startsWith is not a function

After doing some research I found that the topic name had to be a string. I then converted the topic name to a string, `123.toString();`, and now the error that I am getting is:

> Unhandled error FirebaseMessagingError: Malformed topic name

What can I do to fix this and why does the topic parse as number using the REST API and not the `admin.messaging().send(message)` method?

Comment: First it would be great to post an example of what your message object looks like. Without knowing what you are sending within your message object it is a bit hard to tell BUT the error message tells you a bit about the error. Probably you have some characters within your topic that are not allowed. i.e. `topic: "matchday1()"` --> Malformed topic BUT `topic: "matchday"` --> VALID topic

Comment: Hi, thank you for your response. I managed to sort out this issue. I am now confronted with a new issue. I am sending messages from my server via callable cloud function. The console log shows that the data is being received and the response from FCM is that the message was successfully sent. I managed to receive one message on my device but subsequent messages are not being received. I will create a new question for this along with the code etc.